# I'm not sure this question about wine sales commissions is off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

This question about [wine sales commissions](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/what-is-the-average-percentage-of-commission-of-a-commission-only-wine-represent) I thought was an edge case. Not sure what harm it does by leaving it here. I don't know the inner workings of SE (although I am a programmer) and just want to contribute my knowledge of the world of alcohol. IMHO, this seems harmless. What do others think?

Answer (score 2):

My main issue with the question is that there is no real question

> Just ***checking*** other ***views*** on what commission wine representatives make
>   off sales.

They are opening a broad question about commission on wine I left a notice on this post for a bit more explanation which I left on there for 48hrs as nothing was changed I put the question on hold until changes were made. While the title of the question does have an actual question, they need to expand on the question and ask for what they want not just *views*.

Your answer is totally fine and answers what I assume is his question but I'm trying to stop these kind of worded questions as it does not really help when people looking for a answer on Wine commission.

Once the question has been made more clear by the owner, I'm sure it will be re-opened but at the moment I think that this question is badly worded so is not much help to anybody.